# Calculate total Hours Between two date times in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I am stuck  in a fairly simple question. I want to subract two JS dates and calculate the total hours between them and if differnce is more than one hour I want to invoke some code.

Here is what I tried:

```
var timeDiffInMilliSeconds=Math.abs(new Date() - (new Date(rows[i].unixTime*1000))); //get total milliseconds
var timeDiffInHours=timeDiffInMilliSeconds/3600000; //get total hours
if(timeDiffInHours>=1){
    rows[i].statusCode=0;
}
```

but it is not giving me a higher difference than expected. Can anyone please point out the problem?

**EDIT:**

**The Above method is correct.** In my case it was a problem with the UnixTime Calculation. Thanks to **@DarekKay** for pointing out the right error.

Comment: I suggest you elaborate what you mean by _"it is not giving me correct values"_

Comment: Yeah, what are you getting for the output? Also you don't need to convert the diff to hours, you can just check in your `if` if it's bigger than 3600 seconds.

Comment: I am getting 25.3324 but it should be 1.5 hours

Comment: Debug your code: what actual value hides behind `rows[i].unixTime`?

Comment: @DarekKay Thank you.! Please post this as answer so that I can mark it as correct.  There was a problem in UnixTime Calculation and I was trying to find the error somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct, so the value behind `rows[i].unixTime` has to be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to directly subtract the date objects from one another.

For example:

```
var hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;
```

The subtraction returns the difference between the two dates in milliseconds. 36e5 is the scientific notation for 60*60*1000, dividing by which converts the milliseconds difference into hours.

Comment: I have done the same thing in my question. I've just used two steps and you've used one.